# Undefined Error in Golang

Tags: go, methods, struct

I have the following structure:

```
/*gotime.go*/
package gotime

type Now struct {
    dnow int
    ynow int
    mnow time.Month
}
```

And is there a function like:

```
/*gotime.go*/
func (n Now) DayNow() int {
    n.dnow = time.Now().Day()
    return n.dnow

}
```

I'm getting the following error when I want to call this package:

```
/*main.go*/
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./gotime"
)

blah := Now
fmt.Println(blah.DayNow())
```

I get errors:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:5: imported and not used: "_/C_/Users/ali/Desktop/test/gotime"
.\main.go:10: undefined: Now
```

You can look at all of the package on GitHub:

[Link](https://github.com/aligoren/gotime/blob/master/gotime.go) for this package

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `blah := gotime.Now{}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Now` is a struct, you need a struct [Composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to create a value of that type.

Also since it is from another package, you need the [Qualified name](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers):

```
blan := gotime.Now{}
```

**Notice that you have to prepend the package name: package-name.foo**.

Also since you are modifying it, you should / need to use a pointer receiver:

```
func (n *Now) DayNow() int {
    n.dnow = time.Now().Day()
    return n.dnow
}
```